# How can I get IntelliJ to flag any implement of toString()?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, tostring, intellij-inspections

We use Lombok, and my architect wants us to always use the Lombok `@ToString` instead of custom implementation.

I want IntelliJ to flag any `toString()` implementation as a warning.

How do I do that?

I use IntelliJ Ultimate 2023.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [create your own inspections](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-custom-inspections.html).

Go to Settings -> Editor -> Inspections, and click on the "+" button:

[image]

Choose either "Add Structural Search Inspection" or "Add Structural Replace Inspection" depending on whether you want a "quick fix" to the problem.

Here's an example of finding a class with a `toString` in it, and replacing it with the same class but with that method removed, and adding a `@ToString` annotation.

Find:

```
class $ClassName$ {
    public String toString() {
        $Statements$;
    }
    $OtherMembers$
}
```

Note that there is a count modifier on `$Statements$` allowing 0 or more instances

(Since this is powered by [Structural Search](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace.html), `public String toString()` also matches `final` `toString` methods, among other things.)

Replace with:

```
@lombok.ToString
class $ClassName$ {
    $OtherMembers$
}
```

[image]

Note that this will highlight the whole class, because the whole class needs to be replaced.

---

Alternatively, you can just *find* instances of `toString`. You just need to find:

```
public String $toString$() {
    $Statements$;
}
```

There is a text modifier on `$toString$` making sure that its text is always `toString`. Doing it this way allows you to set the target of the match to `$toString$`, highlighting only the `toString` part. Again, there is a count modifier on `$Statements$`. Make sure that the "Language" option is set to "Java - Class Member".

[image]

Finally, here is the XML file exported from the above inspections. You can import this in the inspection settings page.

```xml
<component name="InspectionProjectProfileManager">
  <profile version="1.0">
    <option name="myName" value="Some Name" />
    <inspection_tool class="SSBasedInspection" enabled="true" level="WARNING" enabled_by_default="true">
      <searchConfiguration name="No toStrings" uuid="7d07a3df-3fe8-3f60-9714-6cd79f56ae5e" text="public String $toString$() {&#10;    $Statements$;&#10;}" recursive="true" caseInsensitive="true" type="JAVA" pattern_context="member">
        <constraint name="__context__" within="" contains="" />
        <constraint name="Statements" minCount="0" maxCount="2147483647" within="" contains="" />
        <constraint name="toString" regexp="toString" target="true" within="" contains="" />
      </searchConfiguration>
      <replaceConfiguration name="No toStrings wtih replacement" uuid="6ad09c43-eac2-3f8f-b2c3-8061201ea2ad" text="class $ClassName$ {&#10;    public String toString() {&#10;        $Statements$;&#10;    }&#10;    $OtherMembers$&#10;}" recursive="false" caseInsensitive="true" type="JAVA" pattern_context="default" reformatAccordingToStyle="true" shortenFQN="true" replacement="@ToString&#10;class $ClassName$ {&#10;    $OtherMembers$&#10;}">
        <constraint name="__context__" within="" contains="" />
        <constraint name="Statements" minCount="0" maxCount="2147483647" within="" contains="" />
        <constraint name="ClassName" within="" contains="" />
        <constraint name="OtherMembers" within="" contains="" />
      </replaceConfiguration>
    </inspection_tool>
  </profile>
</component>
```

Comment: @AndyTurner I just tested that, and yes it does!

Comment: surprising, but nice. Perhaps mention in the answer?